# C# REST API communication

Tags: c#, rest, ssl

I've a C#/WPF application that connects to a Java REST API. Job url is: "https://myDevServer:7655/myTestJob". The method on the server returns a string called "success".

When I hit this url using POSTMAN software on my machine, I get a "success" message in the response back from the java API, as  expected.

But when I try to programmatically send request through C# app running on my machine, I get a message saying:
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
My C# code :

```
        var restClient = new MyRestClient("https://myDevServer:7655");
        var request = RequestFactory.CreatePOST("/myTestJob");
        var response = (RestResponse<List<string>>)restClient.Execute<List<string>>(request);
        restClient.ValidateResponse(response);
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Have you tried getting a valid SSL certificate and using it in your code?

Comment: You tagged this with java?

Comment: @InsertKnowledge - the API is java-based. Although I agree; Doesn't really seem relevant to the issue in this case.

Comment: what version of .NET are you using? 4.6+ will handle TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by default